# How to remap "use tool" button?

Tags: customization, shortcut, tools

In the node editor there are three tools available in the <kbd>T</kbd> panel, box select, annotate, and link cut. I'm trying to figure out where the bindings for these tools are configured? By default it seems the "box select tool" allows use of the other two via the 2.8 keybinds for draw (<kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Tweak LMB</kbd>) and link cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tweak RMB</kbd>), while with the link cut tool active, <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Tweak LMB</kbd> doesn't annotate.. only ever link cuts?

Anyway I'd like to achieve 2.7x behavior (link cut on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tweak LMB</kbd>), but even with the correct binding set in the keymap, I only get the behavior of the selected tool when I drag LMB.